# Scalable data model learning materials

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling, postgresql-9.4, nosql

I'm looking for a set of books/materials that help me redesign our existing data model.

Currently we have a relational database with MySQL that has a lot of related tables. I'm looking for a better solution to minimize the JOINs/Lazy loading count and yet still keep the relational structure. I've been looking for PostgreSQL 9.4 (with JSONB capabilities), but I'm unable to find good up to date books that cover data modelling using relational and JSON format.

I have ~5 years experience in working with MySQL (and a little bit Postgres). I have experience creating relational data models from the begginning and also worked with existing small-to-medium systems (~500k new entries per month).

**Backstory (maybe it's helpful)**

We are a startup (direction for global market) and currently have about ~100 daily users (growing) on our website. This has brought up our attention that we should start thinking about our scaling strategy.

The first issue I see in our system is our data model. Our model is built on MySQL and has quite many FK related tables. Sharing this kind of structured data between servers would be quite difficult. 
So our plan is to redesign our database to support horizontal scaling a bit more (we have small user count at the moment so redesigning data model is a bit easier).

Important would be to mention that since we are creating and killing features weekly basis, then database is still growing. Some bottlenecks have identified themselves, but it's still unclear as of what kind of data needs more scaling in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good books on building data models of all types, not one of them is going to suggest getting rid of your foreign keys and moving to JSON. Adding JSON didn't change the way databases are designed thus no one rewrote their database books for it. Relational Databases are relational on purpose and are quite scalable.

If you want a good series of books on tricky database design issues, I would suggest [Joe Celko](http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celko/e/B000ARBFVQ/ref=sr_tc_2_0?qid=1440440252&sr=8-2-ent)'s excellent books. He can be a little opinionated, but overall he offers a lot of good advice.

If you are having issues with lazy loading, it sounds like your problem may be your ORM and that you have run into the dreaded N+1 issue where you are doing lots of queries where only one will work.

The number of users you are talking about on your database (assuming each user isn't querying a terabyte of data) should be able to run easily on the smallest and cheapest hardware.

JSONB in postgres is not meant to get rid of good database structure (denormalization), It's meant to give you a tool for when you need a document store inside of a table.

For what its worth a startup I worked with had a large Postgres database 150GB+ being accessed by 100K+ users a day with over 100 tables and routinely joining 10+ tables in a single query, and it easily ran on a single (although beefy) database that was replicated and backed up. I have talked to others who would say that is a relatively small database.

You made a remark in your OP that:

> Sharing this kind of structured data between servers would be quite
>   difficult.

If you are talking about sharding your data across multiple database servers. I would advise that you are going down the route of premature optimization. While truly large companies need sharded databases, those are few and far between, most companies particularly startups should not even be thinking about this, they have far more important things to think about.

Comment: Thanks for tips Michael and sorry for the long reply delay. I will take a look at Joe Celko's books. Is there any specific book that you can suggest to me written by him?

Comment: About the scaling issue and database sharding - it's not something I'm very worried about today, but I would still like to know what may come in the future. I think that gradually updating database for the future brings less problems later. Refactoring issues myself earlier with 20-40hrs, instead of doing it a year later with 2 people and 160hrs is quite good trade.